# trying to int.parse multi array string

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

Im doing this:

```
string[,] string1 = {{"one", "0"},{"Two", "5"},{"Three","1"}};
int b = 0;

for(int i = 0; i <= string1.Length; i++)
{
     b = int.Parse(string1[i, 1]); // Error occurs here
}
```

Im getting an error saying that "index extent the limits of the array" (or something like that, the error is in danish).

Comment: **WOW** there are a lot of people posting the same incorrect answer for this one.  Nicely asked question ;-)

Comment: i hope this question gets a "Popular Question" badge. It definitely deserves one. very interesting answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two problems:

- `string1.Length` will return 6, as that's the *total* length of the array
- You're using `<=` for the comparison, so it would actually try to iterate 7 times.

Your `for` loop should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < string1.GetLength(0); i++)
```

The call to `GetLength(0)` here will return 3, as the size of the "first" dimension. A call to `GetLength(1)` return 2, as the second dimension is of size 2. (You don't need that though, as you're basically hard-coding the knowledge that you want the second "column" of each "row".)

See the docs for [`Array.GetLength()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 7):

Your array bounds are incorrect in the loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= string1.Length; i++)
```

should read:

```
for(int i = 0; i < string1.GetLength(0); i++)
```

Two things were wrong: `<=` versus `<` meant you were going one item too far, and `.Length` returns the total length of the array (6) versus `GetLength(0)` which returns the length of the first dimension (3).

Answer (score 2):

You already have the right answer, I'll update mine just to correct it. To right iteration should be

```
        for (int i = 0; i < string1.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            b = int.Parse(string1[i, 1]);
        }
```

Because `i` stands for the length of the first dimension, and the fixed `1` will return the number, that is the second element.

I'm sorry for the wrong answer I gave first.

Comment: Doesn't work, because it *is* a two dimensional array.  Check before posting!

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
for(int i = 0; i <= string1.GetLength(0); i++) 
{ 
b = Int32.Parse(string1[i][0]);
}
```

Your code is refering at index 1 rather than 0 which causes exception known as `Array out of bound`

Answer (score 0):

Change `i <= string1.Length` to `i < string1.Length`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < string1.GetLength(0) ; i++)
{
     b = int.parse(string1[i, 0]); // Error occurs here
}
```

[Array.GetLength Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength)

Gets a 32-bit integer that represents the number of elements in the specified dimension of the Array.

Answer (score 0):

Also worth mentioning that `int.Parse` may throw a `FormatException`, consider [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx).